# How can I render data within nested objects in react?

Tags: reactjs, nested-object

I am working with an API that contains nested objects and I am not sure how to display it. I am reading about using Object.keys but not sure how to do it... help please...

Here is the react code. I need to render prices dynamically.

```
<div>
  <Table responsive striped bordered hover variant="dark">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>% Change</th>
        <th>Market Cap</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      {Object.keys(
        cryptos.map(crypto => (
          <tr key={crypto.id}>
            <td>{crypto.cmc_rank}</td>
            <td>
              <Link to={`/crypto/${crypto.id}`}>{crypto.name}</Link>
            </td>
            <td>{crypto.symbol}</td>
            <td>{`price should be displayed here `}</td>
            <td>{`price change should be displayed here `}</td>
            <td>{`market cap should be displayed here `}</td>
          </tr>
        ))
      )}
    </tbody>
  </Table>
</div>
```

Here is the data source

```
"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "slug": "bitcoin",
        "num_market_pairs": 8203,
        "date_added": "2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
        "tags": [
            "mineable"
        ],
        "max_supply": 21000000,
        "circulating_supply": 18376356,
        "total_supply": 18376356,
        "platform": null,
        "cmc_rank": 1,
        "last_updated": "2020-05-13T10:30:30.000Z",
        "quote": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 8920.68810523,
                "volume_24h": 40828691066.513,
                "percent_change_1h": 0.107841,
                "percent_change_24h": 1.62343,
                "percent_change_7d": -2.5838,
                "market_cap": 163929740386.67194,
                "last_updated": "2020-05-13T10:30:30.000Z"
            }
        }
    },
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go with a solution

```js
<div>
  <Table responsive striped bordered hover variant="dark">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>% Change</th>
        <th>Market Cap</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      { 
        cryptos.length &&
        cryptos.map(crypto => (
          <tr key={crypto.id}>
            <td>{crypto.cmc_rank}</td>
            <td>
              <Link to={`/crypto/${crypto.id}`}>{crypto.name}</Link>
            </td>
            <td>{crypto.symbol}</td>
            <td>{crypto.quote.USD.price}</td>
            <td>{crypto.quote.USD.price * crypto.quote.USD.percent_change_1h}</td>
            <td>{crypto.quote.USD.market_cap}</td>
          </tr>
        )
      )}
    </tbody>
  </Table>
</div>
Here is the data source

"data": [
    {
        "id": 1,
        "name": "Bitcoin",
        "symbol": "BTC",
        "slug": "bitcoin",
        "num_market_pairs": 8203,
        "date_added": "2013-04-28T00:00:00.000Z",
        "tags": [
            "mineable"
        ],
        "max_supply": 21000000,
        "circulating_supply": 18376356,
        "total_supply": 18376356,
        "platform": null,
        "cmc_rank": 1,
        "last_updated": "2020-05-13T10:30:30.000Z",
        "quote": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 8920.68810523,
                "volume_24h": 40828691066.513,
                "percent_change_1h": 0.107841,
                "percent_change_24h": 1.62343,
                "percent_change_7d": -2.5838,
                "market_cap": 163929740386.67194,
                "last_updated": "2020-05-13T10:30:30.000Z"
            }
        }
    },
```

Price changed I have considered `percent_change_1h * price`. Check for cryptos.length before doing `map` operation.

Comment: Thank you for the response. I tried the above solution before I posted the question here, it does not work... table.jsx:28 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'USD' of undefined

Comment: @Blondish Can you check your cryptos JSON. Error is because it doesn't have quote as key

Comment: "quote": {
            "USD": {
                "price": 8920.68810523,

Comment: This did work.. I had to remove the dummy data that was messing things up :)

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea why you have `{Object.keys(` in there... remove it.

```
<div>
  <Table responsive striped bordered hover variant="dark">
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Rank</th>
        <th>Name</th>
        <th>Symbol</th>
        <th>Price</th>
        <th>% Change</th>
        <th>Market Cap</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      { cryptos.map(crypto => (
        <tr key={crypto.id}>
          <td>{crypto.cmc_rank}</td>
          <td>
            <Link to={`/crypto/${crypto.id}`}>{crypto.name}</Link>
          </td>
          <td>{crypto.symbol}</td>
          <td>{`price should be displayed here `}</td>
          <td>{`price change should be displayed here `}</td>
          <td>{`market cap should be displayed here `}</td>
        </tr>
      )) }
    </tbody>
  </Table>
</div>
```

Having `Object.keys()` essentially returns an array containing the indexes of the array you map from `cryptos`. React needs an array of elements, so you just need iterate through the elements of `cryptos`, and map each item to something React can render.

For example:

```
const dataList = [{ key:'a', value:'Hello' }, { key:'b', value:'World' }];

<div>
  { dataList.map(data => <div key={ data.key }>{ data.value }</div>) }
</div>
```

Will render

```
<div>
  <div>Hello</div>
  <div>World</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I removed Object.keys(). How would the example you are referring to above be applied in my case? could you walk me through?